How to have a code block for a case statement for a switch that assigns a value?
As you know, Java 14 introduced Switch Expressions, switch statements that return a value. (See JEP 361.)
But it doesn't seem to work with case statements that have code blocks.  I'm not sure if I don't have the syntax right or this is disallowed.
I'm curious because it would be inconsistent with non r-value switch statements (first example).  Plus I've seen this in other languages.
    static void foo(String x) {
        // this works
        switch(x) {
            case "hi" -> {
                System.out.print("got hi");
                System.out.println("hello");
            }
            default -> System.out.println("bye");
        }

        // this works
        var y = switch(x) {
            case "hi" -> "hello";
            default -> "bye";
        };

        // is this possible?
        var z = switch(x) {
            case "hi" -> {
                System.out.println("got hi");
                return "hello";  // return "hello" to the z
            }
            default -> "bye";
        };
    }


you can use the keyword yield for that

Of course, you could just write a private method and call it in the case statement.

I added the technical terms and links for *Switch Expressions`, and fixed your mention of Java 12 to Java 14. Verify that I did not change your meaning.

@BasilBourque thanks.  Though the assignable rvalue switch expression was introduced in Java 12.  https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/new-switch-expressions-in-java-12  Apparently yield came in Java 13?

@PaulC No, that was a Preview feature first in Java 12 and then again in Java 13.  The final feature arrived in Java 14.

yield, not return
Java 14 introduced a new yield statement as part of JEP 361: Switch Expressions.
Instead of return, use the restricted identifier yield.
See The Java® Language Specification for details.
Example code:
var z = switch(x) {
    case "hi" -> {
        System.out.println("got hi");
        yield "hello";
    }
    default -> "bye";
};

And this doesn't just work with switches with -> { ... }. You can use it in a labeled switch expression too:
var z = switch(x) {
    case "hi":
        System.out.println("got hi");
        yield "hello";
    default:
        yield "bye"
};

See also part 6 Switch Expressions of Java Language Updates.

I changed your term keyword to the JEP’s term restricted identifier. The JEP makes this interesting distinction, quoting: “Rather than being a keyword, yield is a restricted identifier (like var), which means that classes named yield are illegal.”
